# select case in Datatable datarow in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable which is having 3 columns like IsMonday,Istuesday and IsWednesday,both are string fields having datas like Y and N.I wanted to take each row and return the result in a string.What i wanted to get is,

```
    if a row is Y,N,Y then the output will be 1 3,two is blank since it is N
    if a row is N,N,Y then the output will be   3,one and two is blank since it is N
```

like this,any idea using Linq case statement or any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will turn all the rows into `List<string>`:

```
var columnNames = new[]{"IsMonday","Istuesday","IsWednesday"};
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Select(row=>string.Join("", 
                          dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                            .Where(col=>columnNames.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                            .Select(col=>row.Field<string>(col) == "N" ? " " :
                                         (col.Ordinal+1).ToString()))).ToList();
```

Note that you said something like that `"N"` will be replaced with a *blank*, but looks like you mean a *space*, so I used a space instead, you can just replace it to whatever you want.

If you just want to convert a specific row to a string, it's very similar like this:

```
//the input is row
var rowString = string.Join("", 
                  dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                            .Where(col=>columnNames.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                            .Select(col=>row.Field<string>(col) == "N" ? " " :
                                         (col.Ordinal+1).ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: how can i convert specific column ie. if i am having five fields some of them are integer and how can i specify these three fileds out of them and then convert?

Comment: @AnilkumarM I updated the code, you just need to specify some array storing all the column names you're interested in and use the updated code.

Comment: @AnilkumarM what description you want? the code uses the so-called `LINQ-to-DataSet`, you should search more about `LINQ`, first it converts all the rows into `IEnumerable<DataRow>` using `AsEnumerable()`, then you can perform LINQ query to filter and shape data, for columns we have to use the `Cast<DataColumn>` to turn all columns into `IEnumerable<DataColumn>`.

Comment: how can i query for a single row?

Comment: @AnilkumarM the result you got before is a **List of string**, if you want to select just 1 row (or 1 item), you should know about the criteria/condition to meet/match that row, we will filter for the row you want based on that criteria/condition.

Comment: can u convert c# to vb

Comment: @Cronaldo I'm sorry, I just know a little VB.NET, converting to vb.net is something hard to do to me.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you have a collection of rows returned from your database that looks something similar to this List.

```
var entity = new List<Entity>()
 {
 new Entity(){ IsMonday = "Y", IsTuesday = "N", IsWednesday = "Y"},
 new Entity() { IsMonday = "N", IsTuesday = "N", IsWednesday = "Y"},
 new Entity() { IsMonday = "Y", IsTuesday = "Y", IsWednesday = "N"}
 };
```

To get the expected result you can use a code something like this

```
 foreach (var e in entity)
 {
   var a = e.IsMonday.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "1" : " ";
   var b = e.IsTuesday.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "2" : " ";
   var c = e.IsWednesday.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "3" : " ";
   var s = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", a, b, c);
 }
```

Here the variable 's' contains the result string.